# Internal Provisioning error during existing user provisioning

Tags: scim, onelogin

We're developing a SCIM API and during the integration testing between OneLogin and our application we always run into an error which can be reproduced with the following steps:

1. Create a user in your application with xy@email.com (SCIM username)
2. Create a user in OneLogin with the same email address
3. Add this user to your application
4. OneLogin should recognize that this user is already using that SCIM application so further provisioning action is not required. However, we got an "Internal Provisioning Error"

I can verify that our API has been called and here are the 2 SCIM webrequests related to this flow:

```
GET https://appurl/svc/scim/v1/Users?filter=userName+eq+"xy%40email.com"

{
  "schemas": [
    "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"
  ],
  "totalResults": 1,
  "itemsPerPage": 1,
  "startIndex": 1,
  "Resources": [
    {
      "userName": "xy@email.com",
      "emails": [
        {
          "primary": true,
          "value": "xy@email.com"
        }
      ],
      "id": "94724df5-2338-45a3-8b96-0f68afd273d4",
      "schemas": [
        "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

GET https://appurl/svc/scim/v1/Users/94724df5-2338-45a3-8b96-0f68afd273d4

{
  "userName": "xy@email.com",
  "emails": [
    {
      "primary": true,
      "value": "xy@email.com"
    }
  ],
  "id": "94724df5-2338-45a3-8b96-0f68afd273d4",
  "schemas": [
    "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"
  ]
}
```

After the 2nd GET request OneLogin returns with "Internal Provisioning Error"

Is there something wrong with the response?

Thank you,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the error. In OneLogin firstName and lastName are required however in our application they are not. When OneLogin gets our user it fails to parse the result since we do not return firstname and lastname.

Comment: I've filed a bug with engineering. Seems odd that we're requiring these fields be present even though we ignore them.

Oddly, you're the first SCIM implementation that doesn't return these.

BTW: reach out to us when you're ready, and we'll be happy to get an official connector in our catalog for you: https://developers.onelogin.com/scim/publish-app

Answer (score 0):

We actually *do* need these values for some functionality in our product:

Specifically, we have functionality to get all the users in the target application and then we allow application admins to manually map which user in the application matches which user in the OneLogin directory (Sync users feature & Associate User)

This is used in cases where (for whatever reason) the users' SCIM username doesn't match the value in OneLogin and they need to be manually associated with a particular user record in your app.

Part of the UI to do this shows the Firstname / Lastname of the user in the application to help identify them.

Our fix is going to be to no longer require these fields (and not barf up an error when this happens) but we will start showing these users only by their SCIM username and "UNKOWN" for first/lastname.

Not the best user experience, but hopefully you can see that's the best we can do under the circumstances.